# sqoop export from hive table to postgresql copies duplicate rows

Tags: postgresql, hive, duplicates, export, sqoop

We are trying to copy about 900 million rows from Hive tables to Aurora PostgreSQL (AWS). Since we had a primary key constraint on the target table, it threw constraint violation errors and the copy failed.
So, we tried removing the constraint until the copy is complete. Exact number of rows got copied successfully in 30 mins.
But, when we examine the data, it has several duplicates and several rows from source missing.
Meaning, say we had row-a, row-b, row-c, row-d in source. Now, the destination has exactly 4 rows, but it has row-a, **row-b, row-b**, row-d. That is row-b copied twice and row-c skipped.

With this issue, 1. we cannot add primary key. and 2. We are losing about 1 million original rows in this process.

Below is our export command:

> sqoop export  \
>   -libjars /usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/lib/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.12.1017.jar \
>   --driver com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver \
>   --connect jdbc:postgresql://myClusterEndpoint.rds.amazonaws.com:5455/DB_NAME?sslmode=require&ssl=true
>   \
>   --table myTable   \
>   --export-dir /data/external/myDataFile   \
>   --input-fields-terminated-by "," \
>   --username  myUserNamer  \
>   --password  myPassword  \
>   -m  500  \

Has anybody faced such issue or know about the cause, please do share your experience and help us resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the sqoop export with `--update-mode` ( it can be allowinsert) and `--update-key` where update-key can be your primary key.

And in this process the rows having duplicate primary keys will be handled.